# how to speed up slicer vba code selection

Tags: excel, vba

hope everyone is well.

Ive got this code that makes a slicer selection (first item):

```
Sub test()


Dim sc As SlicerCache

Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_book1")


On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = True 
Next pt

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_book1")
    .ClearManualFilter
    cnt = .SlicerItems.Count
    If cnt > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To cnt
            .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
        Next
    End If
End With

For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
Next pt

exitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox ("Error in updating slicer filters.")
Resume exitHandler
```

somehow, this code works, but it is incedibly show. So, I was wondering whether anyone has any advice re how to properly speed this up?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: This question might better fit to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the pivot table name than slicer.

```
Sub test()


Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim SIName As String
Dim pt As PivotTable, PTF As PivotField

Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_book1")


On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = True 
Next pt

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_book1")
    '.ClearManualFilter
    cnt = .SlicerItems.Count
    If cnt > 1 Then
        SIName  = .SlicerItems(1).Name
    End If
End With

'Pivot is the sheet name where the pivot table is located
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot").Activate
Set pt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("NameOfPivotTable")
'Book is pivot field
Set PTF = pt.PivotFields("Book")
PTF.ClearAllFilters
PTF.CurrentPage = SIName

For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
Next pt

exitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox ("Error in updating slicer filters.")
Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Hope this help